# Mongodb show results by percentage

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a products catalog algorithm that I will control what show to the user :
My db product collection contain 1M docs.

40% - products from price range 0$-100$
25% - products from price range 100$-500$
25% - products from price range 500$-700$
100% - products from price range 700$ and up

I want to produce this in one query and and after I got list of id's that represent this division i want to create another division on the categories.

Let's say that i want to show :

40% - Clothing
20% - Shoes
20% - Accessories
20% - Jewelry

What is the fastest way to done it ?

If the db was sql so i made a subquery for each division (category / price).

Remember my db contain 1M docs!

Thanks a lot =).

Comment: Show your db structure and expected result of the query. Also tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: **Product  Schema:**
_id
name
price
categories (Array)
**Category Schema:**
_id
Name